# Unity accessing rigidBody component with input system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started a new Unity tut using its input system to move a ball. However, the script doesn't seem to be working when I try to move the ball

[image]

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem; //Namespace for accessing InputSystem to control ball

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private float movementX;
    private float movementY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Onmove(InputValue movementValue)
    {
        Vector2 movementVector = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();

        movementX = movementVector.x;
        movementY = movementVector.y;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, 0.0f, movementY);
        rb.AddForce(movement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Force and movement aren’t the same. So for example 1kg of pressure doesn’t move a 10kg object with friction much.

Comment: With respect, that doesn't help me much. I'm a beginner and I want to know why the ball isn't moving. Is it the code or something else?

Comment: Well it should and is not necessarily a coding issue. You haven’t given any indication to values so my point is valid if you add insufficient force and item either doesn’t move or won’t move enough. While there maybe other issues chances are insufficient force. As previously described.

Answer (score 1):

If you did everything else right and the problem is only in your script then changing from `Onmove` to `OnMove` should fix problem

Answer (score 0):

Create in Unity a new InputControl with the name PlayerInputActions and into
Inspector select Generate C# class, Unity autogenerate for you Action Maps , Actions and Binding Property, double click on it to watch, than in a new c# script named NewInputSystem

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class NewInputSystem : MonoBehaviour
{


public Rigidbody rb;
public float moveSpeed = 7.0f;
Vector2 moveDirections = Vector2.zero;

public PlayerInputActions playerControls;

private InputAction move;

private void Awake()
{
    playerControls = new PlayerInputActions();
}

private void OnEnable()
{
    move = playerControls.Player.Move;
    move.Enable();

  }


private void OnDisable()
{
    move.Disable(); 
   

}


void Start()
{
   
    rb =gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    moveDirections = move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
   
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
//change how you want
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(moveDirections.y * moveSpeed, 0,  moveDirections.x * -moveSpeed);
    
}


}
```